# PowerMock mockStatic didn't catch mocked static void method call

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

I try to mock a static void method with PowerMock over Mockito, but it doesn't work so well.

My sample code:

BlackTempleTest.java

```
package com;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.invocation.InvocationOnMock;
import org.mockito.stubbing.Answer;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import com.BlackTempleTest.Illidan;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ Illidan.class, EvilBrother.class })
public class BlackTempleTest {

    Answer<Object> defaultAnswer = new Answer<Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            System.out.println("Haha!");
            return null;
        }
    };

    @Test(expected = AssertionError.class)
    public void testIllidanFight() throws Exception {
        Illidan.startFight();
    }

    @Test
    public void testCheatOnIllidanFight() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Illidan.class, defaultAnswer);

        Illidan.startFight();
    }

    @Test(expected = AssertionError.class)
    public void testEvilBrotherFight() throws Exception {
        EvilBrother.startFight();
    }

    // dont work
    @Test
    public void testCheatOnEvilBrotherFight() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(EvilBrother.class, defaultAnswer);

        EvilBrother.startFight();
    }

    static class Illidan {
        static void startFight() {
            Assert.fail("You are not prepared!");
        }
    }
}
```

EvilBrother.java

```
package com;

import com.BlackTempleTest.Illidan;

public class EvilBrother extends Illidan {

}
```

My problem is, that the nested class is mocked as expected with a combination of @PrepareForTest and PowerMockito.mockStatic, but if the class is in its own class file, these statements don't work.

How can a fix this test?

**Edit:**

With

```
    PowerMockito.doAnswer(defaultAnswer).when(EvilBrother.class, "startFight");
```

it is possible to pipe the bad call through Powermock, however the Assert.fail is executed.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: You are not prepared!
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at com.BlackTempleTest$Illidan.startFight(BlackTempleTest.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.performMethodInvocation(WhiteboxImpl.java:1873)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.doInvokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:773)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.invokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:753)
    at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.invokeMethod(Whitebox.java:466)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.expectation.PowerMockitoStubberImpl.when(PowerMockitoStubberImpl.java:106)
    at com.BlackTempleTest.testCheatOnEvilBrotherFight(BlackTempleTest.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is, you have to mock Illidan instead of EvilBrother, even if you call EvilBrother.startFight because the method is inherited.

```
@Test
public void testCheatOnEvilBrotherFight() throws Exception {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(Illidan.class, defaultAnswer);

    EvilBrother.startFight();
}
```

Comment: I have the same error.but my mock class does not inherit from another class.

Comment: Please post your code. Without it isn't possible to help you.

Comment: I fixed my issue.Thanks for your responce. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50361736/how-to-unit-test-boolean-field-with-resource

Comment: In some cases, a single test framework includes not all necessary tool you need. That is the cause why in the example above PowerMock is used.